# Non-conformable arguments error while using mediate function on lmer models

Tags: r, lme4

I’m using the `mediation` package, and the `mediate` function does not seem to run on models which are rank deficient. Apologies if this has been covered elsewhere, I couldn't find a solution!

This is the data:

```
library(mediation)
library(lme4)

SampleDF <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), TP = c(2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
1L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), Aggress = c(-0.832620203877889, 
-2.17083928837694, 0.0412752320553753, -1.14954850654182, 0.394530461274209, 
2.79705518822542, 1.27369783159035, -0.706239767785773, 1.99423161185012, 
1.01401591155414, 1.2947963951793, 1.59448432872386, 3.30915107021176, 
0.649839992118197, 1.67364305595097, 1.31515490303306, -1.01430239868541, 
3.85679436537527, 2.01425532673615, 1.88769119671479, 0.881950205888468, 
0.608658260516815, 1.60631752555798, 1.1294835506275, 3.44909077049609, 
0.939933101932205, 2.42546001465964, 0.129004496495123, -1.38125053947115, 
0.446646913146972, -0.91135607759862, -0.869533559252935, 3.18618837149224, 
2.06909842831731, 2.43498960020784, 0.71780234555534, 4.79393089361356, 
1.00404261370789, 2.05760942543975, 3.09967044639277, -1.87754861344065, 
-1.68909344430464, 1.68356978655602, 2.24530636259536, -0.049703032320173, 
1.72613825789211, -0.22202935279363, 1.17271031807231, 3.23443954400222, 
4.94831834045414, 4.01572681535312, 4.2446325057606, 4.73492018217745, 
3.68413047251637, 1.9986170702817, 2.57514866757646, 0.247418252383443, 
2.75239178638484, 1.81759451601412, -1.37343635065883, 0.202060266827699, 
-0.509080680405532, 0.164866145559925, -0.643903992757904, 0.211776088476681, 
-0.698055215106278, -2.42464594784637, -0.63356461179584, 0.991267519028382, 
4.59082570946164, 0.76188027439288, -0.278054985817074, -0.676084846968322, 
2.24100868772273, 1.31766961895862, -0.163592250798168, 2.25383810310358, 
2.89469722551686, -0.710927720986295, 3.57808440476625), NegAff = c(9.20765161285986, 
8.72815744224513, 7.17522885795273, 8.96081013957188, 10.6576140405979, 
8.83239691658894, 9.98220333701316, 8.0980821354078, 8.03329807532086, 
10.0106034440752, 8.16107107890137, 7.58043328493964, 9.89396177160074, 
10.0946145064922, 8.3820699942113, 7.67469422372129, 7.40017413815163, 
5.42183670359848, 4.98369409646916, 7.83283902898145, 7.53673817554754, 
6.84058887227061, 8.71214324544199, 6.95197941853074, 4.77745721311293, 
4.95127897392741, 3.30228259878438, 3.14964660802099, 3.35269756919924, 
3.83163698289516, 5.09501605621539, 3.02900671795849, 5.10202639213142, 
8.57767317175461, 8.88492948118718, 5.52346712456517, 6.40388414272001, 
6.35958140413223, 6.2537265953022, 7.45991275947638, 4.99639420983974, 
8.35829392783833, 7.25210901114007, 7.10327100601611, 8.57293287643942, 
6.960038525446, 7.73392707990379, 6.89970437837466, 7.19065864529721, 
4.00674883467054, 3.7320395458049, 5.02961197420618, 1.72172534172773, 
4.92928973107585, 3.57975379100655, 1.61369933629816, 7.93452090371759, 
8.93574364633935, 4.83140661518408, 7.75890102934878, 3.50858957301288, 
6.59441437108218, 4.15980672854661, 4.66158009817731, 5.62407938267519, 
7.06744085529873, 5.31491706033283, 9.52175990345363, 8.03727148170075, 
6.14384314190904, 5.42836504888783, 6.13566159975244, 5.99882740786229, 
4.9050934221603, 6.14103670266915, 6.99530158760542, 6.27735846176842, 
6.46334386323731, 7.46270552345825, 7.47768122159581), Conflict = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Relation = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Location = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-80L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In this made-up example, I’m dealing with intensive longitudinal data, and assessing the impact of conflict incidents (Conflict) on negative affect (NegAff). Specifically, I'm looking at the effect of conflict with friends on negative affect and then investigating whether negative affect mediates the effect of friends conflict on aggression (Aggress).

Alongside the binary variable of whether a conflict occurred, I therefore also have a variable of whether the conflict was with a friend or a stranger (Relation). I then have a covariate of whether it was in-person or online (Location). Both these variables are dependent on the Conflict variable. I’ve therefore created interaction variables by combining both with conflict occurrence to deal with the collinearity, before running lmer models:

```
LocInt <- interaction(SampleDF$Conflict, SampleDF$Location, sep = ":")
RelInt <- interaction(SampleDF$Conflict, SampleDF$Relation, sep = ":")

Mod1 <- lme4::lmer(NegAff~RelInt+LocInt+TP+(1|ID),data=SampleDF,na.action = na.omit)
Mod2 <- lme4::lmer(Aggress~NegAff+RelInt+LocInt+TP+(1|ID),data=SampleDF,na.action = na.omit)
```

Predictably, I get warnings about rank deficiency: `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient` but R removes the redundant columns and I still get meaningful effects for each of the variables.

However, I then get an error when I run the mediation model (The sims are only low to act as an example):
`Med1 <- mediate(Mod1,Mod2, treat="RelInt",control.value = "0:0",mediator="NegAff",sims=20)`

```r
Error: `Error in tcrossprod(MModel.fixef.sim, mmat.t) : non-conformable arguments`
```

This error doesn't occur if I remove the RelInt and LocInt variables, so I'm guessing it's related to the rank deficiency of the models. However, I don't know how to resolve that issue while retaining these covariates in the model.

Is there a way to make these models workable for `mediate`?

Thank you!